How to add one variable part in dataframe name in pyspark?
I want to add today's date in dataframe name.
df_2024_jul_05 = spark.table("tablename")
Here the bold part is dynamic in nature.
I tried the below code:
x = "df\_"+str(date.today())

f"{x}"= spark.sql(f"select \* from tablename")

While trying the above part, im getting the following error:
SyntaxError: cannot assign to f-string expression here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='? (command-4340248393571885-178511402, line 5)


Why do you need dynamic df names? Instead, maybe you should add a column with today's date in the df. I don't think there is a straightforward way to do what you want anyway in Python without a workaround.

Don't do that. The date is part of the data, it shouldn't be part of the code. Use a dict?

How is this specific to Spark? Variable assignments are the same no matter what datatype you're assigning.

As mentioned in the comments, variable variable names are not a good idea in python (see here) and you should consider using a dictionary instead.
x = "df_"+str(date.today())

data_dict = {
    x: spark.sql(f"select * from tablename")

}

